# Error when run a Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a report made in Cystal Reports with c#.I don't know which version of .Net.I want to run an application that open this report but I reveive this error :

```
An unhandled exception has occured in your application.
LOG: DisplayName = CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms, Version=12.0.1100.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
(Fully-specified)
```

Probably I need to install Crystal reports runtime Version=12.0.1100.0 but I don't find it on internet ( I found one on  this site : http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-27917 but ask me for a product id)

Can somebody help me with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You looking for Crystal Report 2008.

You can look here, http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Which+Crystal+Reports+assembly+versions+are+supported+in+which+versions+of+Visual+Studio+.NET to see which version is compatible with which VS.

When installing VS there should be event CR there

Oh, heres the link[Crystal Report 2008](https://smpdl.sap-ag.de/~sapidp/012002523100009747762011E/cr2008fp36_redist.zip)

Comment: I see that this msi is version 12.3 and doesn't works.I need 12.0 .